# acces data from custom widget in qlistwidgetitem

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I can't find anything related in the internet and have been trying for hours now. Maybe also my whole attempt on the code is wrong. Not sure how this is done normally.

I am creating a custom widget with a few lables and an icon inside every row of a qlistwidget.

later on selection change I want to read the current rows , custom widgets data.

But I can't figure out how .

I got this custom widget:

```
class CustomCatalogWidget(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, catalogWidget, size):
        super(CustomCatalogWidget, self).__init__()
        self.mainLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()

        #reconstruct catalog items
        self.thumbnail = catalogWidget.getThumbnailPixmap()
        if not self.thumbnail:
            return
        self.thumbnail = self.thumbnail.scaled(size, size, QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
        self.name = catalogWidget.getNodeName()
        self.thumbnailLocation = catalogWidget.getDiskThumbnailLocation()
        # reconstruct finish
        self.labelImage = QtGui.QLabel()
        self.labelImage.setPixmap(self.thumbnail)
        self.labelName = QtGui.QLabel(self.name)
        self.timestamp = datetime.fromtimestamp(catalogWidget.getRenderEndTime())
        self.labelRenderEndTime = QtGui.QLabel(self.timestamp.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))


        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.labelImage)
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.labelName)
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.labelRenderEndTime)


        self.setLayout(self.mainLayout)
```

which is attached to a qlistwidget inside my main class:

```
self.catalogBox = QtGui.QListWidget()
self.insertThumbnailsFromCatalog(self.catalogBox)
self.catalogBox.selectionModel().selectionChanged.connect(functools.partial (self.catalogBoxSelectionChanged, self.catalogBox))
```

this function is filling the catalogBox from inside the main

```
class:
    def insertThumbnailsFromCatalog(self, boxLayout):
        #CATALOG ROUTINE
        #append all catalog items ot the window.
        boxLayout.clear()
        for catalogItem in CatalogManager.Catalog.GetCatalogItems(slot=1):
            if catalogItem:
                cw = CustomCatalogWidget(catalogItem, self.thumbnailSizeSlider.value())
                itemWidget = QtGui.QListWidgetItem()


                itemWidget.setSizeHint(QtCore.QSize(130,20))
                boxLayout.addItem(itemWidget)
                boxLayout.setItemWidget(itemWidget, cw)
                #catalogBox.addWidget(QHLine())
```

and now I am trying to access the Custom catalog widget on selection changed.
I need to know what is written in the label self.labelName or self.labelRenderEndTime

And I don't seem to find the qlabels inside the qlistwidgetitems.

```
def catalogBoxSelectionChanged(self, boxLayout):
    row = boxLayout.currentRow()
    currentItem = boxLayout.currentItem()

    for ch in currentItem.listWidget().children():
        if ch.__class__.__name__ == 'QAbstractListModel':
            print ch.children()
            print dir(ch)
    #for x in boxLayout.currentItem().listWidget().children():
    #    if x.__class__.__name__ == 'QWidget':
    #print x.children()
```

Answer (score 0):

oh actually I found out how to access it:

```
for ch in currentItem.listWidget().children():
    for x in ch.children():
        for i in x.children():
            if i.__class__.__name__ == 'QLabel':
                print i.text()
```

Comment: use `boxLayout.itemWidget(currentItem)`